# neo4j get nodes where first letter of name is some letter

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to get all nodes whose name starts with an "A"

```
match n where substring(n.name, 0,1) = "a" return n
```

returns zero results. What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I was searching for lowercase "a", and all node names started with an uppercase letter. In order to make the cases match, I had to add a `lower` function wrapper to the `n.name` string.

```
MATCH n
WHERE substring( lower( n.name ), 0, 1 )
RETURN n
```

Answer (score 2):

```
MATCH (n) where substring(n.name,0,1) = 'a'
RETURN n
```

You're missing parentheses

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a regular expression match for this:

```
MATCH n
WHERE n.name =~ '(?i)a.*'
RETURN n
```